# MVC - The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have read various posts around the message

> The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'

I have made sure I have included the `Http` attribute. I have tried both `System.Web.HttpPost` and `System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost`

I have also included the `[FromBody]` tag

I have an angularjs page trying to post to a MVC method

Here is my angularjs call

```
$http({
    url: '/api/entry',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', /*or whatever type is relevant */
        'Accept': 'application/json' /* ditto */
    },
    data: {
        'data': $scope.userEntry
    }
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.Message = "Saved successfully";
    $scope.working = false;
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.title = "Oops... something went wrong";
    $scope.working = false;
});
```

Here is my MVC method

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
private async void Post([FromBody] UserEntry userEntry)
{   
    if (userEntry.UserEntryID > 0)
    {
        // update
        var dbUserEntry = this.db.UserEntries
                .Where(u => u.UserEntryID == userEntry.UserEntryID)
                .FirstOrDefault();

        dbUserEntry.TeamName = userEntry.TeamName;            
    }
    else { 
        // insert
        this.db.UserEntries.Add(userEntry);
    }

    await this.db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

No matter what I try, I cannot access my Post method and keep getting the same error mentioned above.

Comment: remove the `headers` from your script block, and try again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is *private*.
Make it **public** and it should work much better.

As a side note, you may want to reconsider using async with void.

> Prefer async Task methods over async void methods

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 1):

@David it seems like there is a confusion here as you have used`/api/` which is default route for **web api** but you have mentioned you are using **mvc**.
It's web api if your controller is inherited from `ApiController`. In that case `System.Web.Http.Post` attribute would make the difference.
Though you have to make the method public to make it work in any case as @smoksnes mentioned.

Comment: As per the question, he is using mvc, not wep api.